# Representação de instruçoes assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Como interpretar uma instrução Assembly com seu valor hexadecimal em um endereço de memória?

`8B 4C 24 04` CORRESPONDE A ISSO -> `MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4]`

Mas se tivesse só os valores hexadecimais como chegaria a esta instrução Intel x86?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes do que você quer. Mostre exemplos. Com perguntas pela metade você não consegue nem 10% de uma resposta. E vê se a *tag* está certa também. Não coloque qualquer uma. Coloque uma que ajude identificar o problema.

Comment: Esses são Opcodes. Você tem que olhar no manual do processador. Esse [site](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x8B) também pode ajudá-lo

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Nem tente fazer isto. É trabalho insano. Se quer fazer isto é melhor pegar um [*disassembler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler). [Veja alguns disponíveis](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers).

Se quiser fazer esta insanidade tem que ler toda documentação do processador. É bem mais complicado do que imagina, até para os programadores de baixo nível mais experientes.