# Como funciona e qual é a síntaxe do código de máquina?

Tags: assembly, descompilação

Preciso entender como funciona o código de máquina, por exemplo, os declaramentos das instruções e como pode se tornar legível como o Assembly, onde poderei ver instrução como `mov`, "interpretar". Adicionalmente, por que fizeram esses símbolos? Não sei nomear nada.

Para ideia, compilei um código simples em um compilador de Assembly que abre uma caixa de mensagem dizendo algo.

Convertido de hexadecimal para texto pelo bloco de notas do MS Windows:

[image: Executável]

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "como funciona?"? Seja mais específico na sua dúvida. Este código foi escrito em Assembly? Então ele não foi compilado, e portanto não faz sentido falar em descompilação.

Comment: @bigown Se ele está assim é porque está compilado, não? Cheio de símbolos. Esse não é o Assembly e fui específico, mas veio do Assembly!

Comment: Assembly não é código de maquina, o código de maquina e composto por 0s e 1s, e o tamanha da palavra varia, depende da arquitetura do processador.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Mas foi dito que ele é. Estou sendo enganado pelo jeito...

Comment: @TheProHands Assembly é uma linguagem de montagem para tornar o código de maquina legível para o ser-humano, e ela varia também para cada tipo de processador, depende da família de processadores, cada família já tem suas instruções já definida em Assembly.

Comment: Eu não sei se o que você quer aprender é código de maquina ou Assembly.

Comment: @TheProHands não, compilação é outra coisa. Algumas coisas que podem lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101. Se acha que alguém lhe ensinou errado, seria bom colocar onde viu isso. E não foi específico, a dúvida é muito geral. Não dá para saber o que você realmente quer saber. A não ser que esteja pedindo para escrevermos um capítulo de um livro sobre o funcionamento de códigos, aí a pergunta não cabe mesmo. Se for mais específico pode salvá-la.

Comment: Outras que podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91775/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109886/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101

Comment: Vou repetir, não existe compilador de Assembly. Existe *assembler*, ou seja, montador. Até existe compilador (se é que pode se chamar assim de macros para Assembly, mas aí é outra coisa.

Comment: @bigown Sim, entendi. Ou seja, o código de máquina é o Assembly. É sempre dito que não sou específico, mas queria saber o que cada símbolo significa, foi algo assim que perguntei. Enfim, achei o que estava querendo, dificilmente. Os mais velhos de 16 anos para cima parecem querer esconder o Assembly e sua documentação para ninguém mais aprender, por incrível que pareça.

Comment: Não. Código de máquina é uma coisa, Assembly é outra. Ah, você quer um manual completo disso. Tem livros de com mais de 1000 páginas que mostram isso. Isso não é nada específico. É, deve existir uma conspiração dos mais de 16 anos.

Comment: @bigown Livros completamente impossíveis de ser achados, como sempre. Não citam muito esses símbolos, por isso fico confuso.

Comment: Você pode usar o OllyDbg para realizar essa engenharia reversa.

Comment: @Laerte O que eu iria fazer é o que essas ferramentas fazem, embora para outro tipo de projeto sem uso dessas ferramentas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tentando responder superficialmente, esse é um arquivo em determinado formato, assim como existem formatos de banco de dados, textos, planilhas, imagens, etc. Esse é um formato que o sistema operacional reconhece e sabe o que fazer com o conteúdo dentro. Ali contém instruções de como colocar o conteúdo relevante na memória. Também tem as instruções e os dados estáticos da aplicação. Pode-se entender isto como um "textão" que algum componente saberá como lidar. Não é um texto puro porque permite caracteres extras que não estão presentes em textos, por isso é chamado de binário.

O sistema operacional dirá ao processador que deve executar as instruções contidas ali (dentro do seu sistema interno de agendamento) e este passará "interpretar" aqueles caracteres para decidir o que fazer dentro dele.

Algumas arquiteturas possuem instruções de tamanho fixo e outras de tamanho variável. Cada caractere ou conjunto de caracteres indicam qual instrução deve ser executada e que "operandos" serão usados nesta operação. O processador processará os bits desses operandos (se tiver algum) ou de algum registrador ou outra coisa previamente definido pela instrução. Depois ela vai para a próxima instrução - eventualmente uma instrução pode alterar qual é a próxima (desvio). Na maioria dos sistemas operacionais isto ocorre até que uma sinalização definida previamente devolva o controle para o sistema operacional.

Isso pode ser melhor visto em [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

É bem mais complexo que isso, mas já estou me alongando. O importante é que cada caractere desses indica algo que o processador sabe o que fazer. No fundo os caracteres são números conforme a tabela ASCII estendida - é mostrado assim porque pode facilitar a leitura em algo que está sendo interpretado como um texto comum (afinal foi usado um editor de texto), é possível ver de outras formas, dá até para ver os bits deles, cada um escolhe como quer visualizar.

Um código escrito em linguagem de alto nível pode ser compilado para gerar isso, ou um código em Assembly pode ser montado. Há uma relação direta 1:1 entre as instruções Assembly e esses caracteres (em conjunto). Portanto o código de máquina pode ser facilmente convertido para o Assembly bruto aproximado que o gerou (longe de ser legível) por um [desmontador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler). O Assembly é um código "mais fácil" de um humano ler - inclusive porque possui comentários, o código de máquina é mais fácil para o computador.

Um utilitário adequado para ver código binário é o [`objdump`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) ou [`dumpbin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019).

Os *links* nos comentários ajudam dar uma ideia melhor do assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Assembly/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando se diz uma linguagem de "alto nível" você quer dizer "linguagem com mais acesso ao sistema"? (sim, sei que não importa a síntaxe, mas o compilador) É possível gerar aqueles símbolos para gerar um arquivo executável (por exemplo) sem digitar eles? PS::: eu acho que quase no mesmo dia que fiz a questão estava fazendo algo errado com alguma referência no Wikipédia que embora podia estar certa. Lá tem umas referências de instruções e seu caractere hexadecimal, pude pressentir símbolos lá.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57309/101  Eu acho que você supõe coisas que não fazem sentido. Não consegui entender sua dúvida aí. De qualquer forma, parece ser uma pergunta nova, então abra uma nova. Tá vendo como não era específico.